# SQL DB2 Toad - Sum from two tables by ID

Tags: sql, group-by, db2, toad

I was hoping to find the sum from two tables with columns ID and Amount, grouping by ID.
My first attempt was to UNION the two tables first and then conduct a sum and group by, but I was hoping to know of a better way.

Inputs:

Table 1

```
ID    Amount
123   100
123   100
145   500
167   600
```

```
Table 2
ID    Amount
123   100
123   100
145   500
199   600
```

Output

```
ID    Amount
123   400
145   1000
167   600
199   600
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
select id, sum(amount) as amount 
from (
  select id, amount from table_1
  union all
  select id, amount from table_2
) x
group by id
```